# Is there a way to remove spaces after tags

Tags: xslt

i've the below part of xml.

```
    <para>There are three types of investment vehicles available for foreign investors, i.e. Chinese-Foreign equity joint venture, Chinese-Foreign cooperative joint venture and wholly foreign-owned enterprises.<footnote num="8">
                    </footnote>
</para>
```

here when i'm trying to apply my template it is creating a blank space and it is as follows.

```
<xsl:template match="footnote">
        <sup><a><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>f</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#ftn.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
            </a>
        </sup>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

the output i get is

```
<sup>
<a name="f8" href="#ftn.8" class="tr_ftn">8</a>
</sup>
```

but when i try the below template

```
    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <sup><xsl:text>Hi</xsl:text><a><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>f</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#ftn.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
            </a>
        </sup>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

The output i get is

```
<sup>Hi<a name="f8" href="#ftn.8" class="tr_ftn">8</a>
</sup>
```

Actual expected output is

```
<sup><a name="f8" href="#ftn.8" class="tr_ftn">8</a>
    </sup>
```

please let me know if there a way to get the 3rd output(i.e. with no space and no displaying text) in my template.

Html output(here actually 8 is superscripted) for first case is

wholly foreign-owned enterprises. <sup>8</sup> See,

and for second case is

wholly foreign-owned enterprises.<sup>Hi8</sup> See,

expected

wholly foreign-owned enterprises.<sup>8</sup> See,

Thanks

Comment: The templates you've shown here won't work as you haven't closed the `<xsl:template>` tags properly. Can you show a complete example of the XSLT you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` and you can remove that or use `<xsl:output indent="no"/>`.